# prevent default onkeyup event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onkeydown, onkeyup

Logically prevent default doesn't work with on key up.But i have to achieve something like that...

i have to make a text field something like when user enters value it has to check it is 3 digit an should allow maximum 2 fraction precision(eg:123.99,24,56).So i want to read the values and call a JavaScript function and have to prevent it if it doesn't fit.

If i use key down i cannot trace the value like user may place a character in middle of the digit.So is there any way to achieve this...

Comment: Use [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) instead of `onkeyup`.

Comment: thank you... but apex page is not supporting this attribute

Comment: There's nothing about "apex" in your question. What is it?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i was trying to add it in salesforce apex pages... but wheni use in normal html it's working really great.. but apex pages are not supporting this oninput

Comment: Well, then you've to manipulate the entered value with RegExp, and re-write the whole value of an input rather than trying to prevent user to enter what ever (s)he likes.

Comment: @Teemu I wasn't aware of oninput, thank you very much. I can use this myself. I like to avoid applying inline event attributes `oninput=""`  so when I apply this event attribute I will need to use addEventListener('`input`',something,false); . Thank you very much!

Comment: it is working in apex pages too when i add html_ in before on input....  please add this in answer.. so that it would help others ... thank you @Teemu

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
var elt = document.getElementById('test');

function saveLastInput(e) {
    e.target.setAttribute('last-input', elt.value);
}

function forbidNonNumbers(e) {
    var elt = e.target,
        newValue = elt.value,
        lastInput,
        newValueIsForbidden = false;

    if (newValue !== '' && !/^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/.test("" + newValue)) {
        newValueIsForbidden = true;
    }

    if (newValueIsForbidden) {
        lastInput = elt.getAttribute('last-input');
        elt.value = lastInput;
    }
}

elt.addEventListener(elt.oninput ? 'input' : 'keyup', forbidNonNumbers); 
elt.addEventListener(elt.oninput ? 'input' : 'keyup', saveLastInput); // Insert this line last!
```

Tested in Chrome, FF, IE 11

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hc5fyLyz/1/